# In what context is the plural of genius, "genii" acceptable to use in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, grammatical-number, latin, irregular

How exactly can one acceptably use ***genii*** in a sentence? Can it be used in everyday language, or does it have a very specific ruleset about how and where it may be used?

Comment: Only when talking about the mythological creatures that grant wishes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal plural is "geniuses"; "genii" is not used in everyday language.

The word "genius" does come from Latin, but it's gone through a long journey to get to English and its meaning has shifted quite a bit along the way. So it is pluralized according to the normal English pattern.

The issue is complicated a bit by the fact that the Latin word, with the Latinate plural "genii", does continue to be used in English for some specialist meanings.

The [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/genius) online mark the plural "genii" as being used for the following senses of the word:

> a guardian spirit associated with a person, place, or institution.

as well as

> The prevalent character or spirit of something such as a nation or
>   age:
>   
> '*Boucher’s paintings did not suit the austere genius of neoclassicism*'

However, they indicate the usual "geniuses" for the now rather rare and archaic meaning

> A person regarded as exerting a powerful influence over another for
>   good or evil: 
>   
> '*he sees Adams as the man’s evil genius*'
>   
> '*this young man is my good genius, my guardian angel*'

One last note: even when the English word is being used in one of its more common senses, "genii" might also be used as a joking plural, since using fancy Latinate plurals for ordinary words can sound funny to English speakers. I wouldn't consider that kind of joke "everyday language," though.

Comment: Yeah. It's important to note that English as a general rule doesn't normally want you to conjugate or pluralize loan words in the language they are borrowed from. If you've already borrowed the word, it's English now and you should treat it as such. It's pastas not paste, orangutans not orang-orang utan and bazaars not bazaarha.

Comment: @ChrisSubagio exactly... When you conjugate English words, particularly words from Latin, you tend to sound like the nerdy character on a sitcom.

Comment: @ChrisSubagio Pasta doesn't have a plural, its uses are either as a collective or as an uncountable.

Comment: Ah, but you can pluralize pasta when referring to types of pasta. Here are three pastas: Spaghetti, Rotini, and Cascatelli.

Answer (score 2):

"Genii" has unfortunate collisions with the plural of "genie" (itself a  form of the Arabic *jinn*, an evil spirit) and of the Roman *genius*, a guardian spirit. Stick with "geniuses."

Comment: But, "genii" and "genie" (and "genies," and "jinn") are all pronounced differently. I'm mot sure what collision you mean.

Comment: @sumelic Have you been wondering about this for 113 days?  The collision is one of orthography.  Someone reading out loud won't know how to pronounce the word if it's say, the first word in a sentence.

Comment: I happened to be googling "genius plural".  Looks like this answer [gets google's vote](http://i.imgur.com/4NzZNOs.png)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma  Thanks for the link, which I find somehow frightening.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use `genii` instead of `geniuses` when you don't want to be easily understood.

Comment: Or if you're *talking* to geniuses, who presumably will be smart enough to understand you easily! :)

Comment: Or if you're talking to (or about) people who think they are geniuses, and you want to make fun of them.

Answer (score -3):

Both - Genii & Geniuses should be acceptable. 
Geniuses is longer, Genii is frugal, follows logicaly, is easy to understand.
Genii does not clash with the plural of genie, which would be genies. 
When spoken, geniuses can be retained, avoiding the cringeworthy 
  factor associated with saying genii.

Comment: Hi Rocket Man, welcome to EL&U. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by citing other sources. Your current answer adds nothing (other than personal opinion) to the existing answers, and is [incorrect re the plural of genie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genie). For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)