# What is the plural of the word "genius"?

Tags: grammar

This one has been troubling me for a while.

Genius is a Latin derivative. Words that are stolen from other languages, as far as I know, almost always retain their plural form in that language.

For example, radius - radii.

So is the plural for genius genii or geniuses? Genii is also, I believe, the plural for genie (djinn from middle east mythology).

Edit: I mean genius as the very intelligent human being.

Which version is more acceptable in daily language?

Comment: Whoever "stole" it from Latin, he was a genius.

Comment: Yeah. *rolls eyes*

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: @Mitch dictionary.reference.com says genius for 2, 3, 8 people and genii for 6, 7, 9, 10 (which sounds weird to me; what happens to 4, 5, 11+?), Merriam-Webster says both are used, the OED says genius only. I guess I meant to ask which is more acceptable in everyday speech.

Comment: You should add that to your question, otherwise this is closable as general reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what context is the plural of genius, "genii" acceptable to use in a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258692/in-what-context-is-the-plural-of-genius-genii-acceptable-to-use-in-a-sentence)

Comment: See Oald, genius - geniuses. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/genius_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to use "genii" (pronounced /ˈdʒiːniaɪ/), but only if you are using the word to mean **"a nature spirit or an elemental spirit"**:

> **genius**: pl. **genii** Roman Mythology. A tutelary deity or guardian spirit of a person or place.

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=genius))

According to the American Heritage Dictionary, if you use "genius" in any other meaning, including "an extremely intelligent human being", the correct plural form is "geniuses".

Other dictionaries may list [more meanings of the word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/genius?s=t), but the point remains that e.g. **three persons with extraordinary mental capacity are geniuses**, with "genii" reserved to various kinds of spirits.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't make my meaning clear enough. Edited the original post. If I was referring to a bunch of super intelligent scientists, for eg., would I refer to them as geniuses or genii?

Comment: @WillHunt I don't see how this changes things, though. My answer always included the qualification that "genii" is limited to a particular meaning of "genius". **If you use the word to mean "an intelligent person" then the plural can only be "geniuses".**